# How to send action from my app to other app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplication

I want to send action from my iOS app to other app

```
UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSString *URLEncodedText = @"...";
NSString *ourPath = [@"...://" stringByAppendingString:URLEncodedText];
NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
if ([ourApplication canOpenURL:ourURL]) {
    [ourApplication openURL:ourURL];   
}
else {
    //Display error
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"..." message:@"..." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

Now, open second app from my app, but I want send action to second app.

Comment: I don't understand.Please explain in detail.

Comment: i want run 1 method on your second app is possible?

Comment: Pass the first app of the iTunes  url . It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Apple added Actions to iOS8 to manage this kind of problems. You can check the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Services.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH13-SW1).
This way you can offer "services" as Actions to another apps or, if it's your case, consume that actions offered by third party apps.

Comment: i want run 1 method on your second app
is possible?